# PHP Associative Array issue

Tags: php

I have the following PHP.

If the user enters "Ben" in the name field of the form, I'd like my script to output **37**.

I've tried `echo $age[$value2];` but no joy :(

```
<?php    
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
echo "Peter is " . $age['Peter'] . " years old.";

// how old is $value2?
$value2 = $_GET['name']; // if they enter "Ben"
echo $age[$value2]; //
```

Comment: Try using `echo $age[{$value2}];`

Comment: @Ajith I am getting an error when I try this.

Comment: This works `$age{$value2};`

Comment: [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c409bd0fceb30f0772eadd4ba4de57e313eebc9), work your code too

Comment: @michaelmcgurk You shouldn't use curly braces, if they aren't deprecated in current PHP versions they will be(I don't have the link with the info but I can get it if needed)

Comment: Double check the value of `$value2` (`var_dump($value2);`), your code should work **if** `$value2` is equal to one of the keys in `$age`. Btw, feel free to write the exact error you're getting.

Comment: What's your error? https://imgur.com/a/659j4cS

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo What would you recommend as a way of doing this? : )

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Several ways: You can add `var_dump($value2);` right after setting that variable. Or you can try `var_dump(isset($age[$value2]));`. Perhaps both lines.Could you get back with the output from it? (Add those lines in the right spot, run the code to get the output, copy'n'paste it here.)

Comment: Would you mind sharing the original `$_GET` request and how it is generated? I think that `$value2` does not contain the actual name and so the `echo` is unable to print anything since there's no match. Do check that the name you enter to the `$_POST['name']` is with the proper capitalization. You can ensure this by converting the first character of the actual string to a capital letter using the the `ucfirst();` function. So you would do `$value2 = ucfirst($_GET['name']);` and then `echo $age[$value2];`.